# ViewPager as a header of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I want to make a listView that contains a viewPager as header .. but every time I run my app it crashes showing that error happens when I try to the set the adapter to the pager although it works separately when I cancel the listview thing .. is there anyway to make a viewpager and listview below it ?!

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

AppManager appManager;
ListView listView;
ViewPager pager;
NewsPagerAdapter pAdapter;
private int img[] = {
        R.drawable.logo1new, R.drawable.image_list_loading };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the app manager instance 
    appManager = AppManager.getInstance();
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pAdapter = new NewsPagerAdapter(this, img);

    new DownloadNews().execute("http://mobrss.youm7.com/rss/service.svc/SelectForSpecifiedSection/SecID/12/page/1");

}

private class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<News>>{

    @Override
    protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return loadXml(params[0]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("IO exceptions", "ture" );
            return null;
        }catch(XmlPullParserException xm){
            Log.d("XML exceptions", "true" );
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<News> result) {
        Log.d("result SIZE", "" + result.size());
        NewsListAdapter adapter = new NewsListAdapter(getBaseContext(), result);
        listView.addHeaderView(pager);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setAdapter(pAdapter);




    }
}


private List<News> loadXml(String url) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    NewsParser newsParser = new NewsParser();

    try{
        stream = Utils.downloadUrl(url);
        appManager.setNews(newsParser.parse(stream));
        Utils.listNews(appManager.getNews());
        Log.d("Appmanager", "the news set apperantly");

    }finally{
        if(stream != null){
            stream.close();
        }
    }
    Log.d("list items","" + appManager.getNews().size());
    return appManager.getListNews() ;

}
```

Comment: Is your ViewPager just above the list, or actually part of the list (i.e. you can scroll it up off the screen)?

Comment: What's the error it gives you? I tried to do something similar since I wanted the `ViewPager` to scroll vertically with the `ListView`.

Comment: the error always in those lines  listView.addHeaderView(pager);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setAdapter(pAdapter);